# What is the purpose of the square root in the significance formula?

Tags: statistical-significance

I encountered (see$^{\dagger}$ [here](http://tmva.sourceforge.net/docu/TMVAUsersGuide.pdf) p.60) the following formula for the signal significance:
$$
S = \frac{\epsilon_S N_S}{\sqrt{\epsilon_S N_S + \epsilon_B(\epsilon_S) N_B}},
$$
where $\epsilon_{S(B)}$ is the signal (background) efficiency and $N_{S(B)}$ is the number of signal (background) events.
I am wondering why it is square root here? Wouldn't it better to remove it in order to provide normalized significance $0 \leq S \leq 1$?

---

$^\dagger$Note the typo there (should be $N_B$ in the second term under square root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a data consisting of elementary event which we denote as $\omega$.
Suppose one constructed a histogram with $k$ bins $\{b_1, b_2, ..., b_k\}$ from that data with $N_{tot}$ events so
$$
\sum_i n_i = N_{tot},
$$
where $n_i$ is a number of events contained in bin $b_i$. Also suppose that it is known how many events should be contained in each bin due to background
$$
n^{(B)}_k = \big|\{\omega\,|\, \omega \in b_k, \omega\text{ is a background event}\}\big|
$$
From that systematized data one can construct a test that estimates how significant the deviation from the background in each bin:
$$
S_k = \frac{N^{(o)}_k - n^{(B)}_k}{\sigma_{n^{(B)}_k}},\label{sk}\tag{*}
$$
where $N^{(o)}_k$ is actual (observed) number of events in the $k$-th bin.

Taking into account that for large $n$ in a bin $\sigma_n\sim\sqrt{n}$ we can rewrite eq.\eqref{sk} as following
$$
S_k = \frac{n^{(S)}_k}{\sqrt{n_k}},
$$
where $n^{(S)}_k$ is interpreted as non-background, signal event.